# PHP if $var equals to 1 set $var2 any number

Tags: php, mysql

$varb and $varx are row entries in database table, they can be "0" or "1". I wanna set $varb2 "1" if $varb is 1(the same option for $varx2).

I have to check each row.

Here is code:

```
if($varb == 1){
 $varb2 == 1;
}elseif($varx == 1){
 $varx2 == 1;
}
```

And I select all entries that have "1" in their varb or varx(or both).

Here is select:

```
SELECT * FROM news_articles
    WHERE varb = '$varb2' OR varx = '$varx2' 
    ORDER BY rand()
    LIMIT 4";
```

Comment: `$varx2 == 1;` is not an assignment..

Comment: please post the corrected version.

Comment: Here you go: Google: `PHP assignment` and have your answer in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Assignments are done by -

```
$a = 2;
$b = 'Hello';
```

But when we compare -

```
$a == 2 || $a != 1
```

Replace `==` with `=` at the time of assigning -

```
if ($varb == 1) {
   $varb2 = 1;
} elseif ($varx == 1) {
   $varx2 = 1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome.. But i would suggest you to go through the basic to make your concept clear. :)

Comment: What about select? is it correct?